# Key-Value Pair Json transformation and conversion into a class in Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Below is the structure of my JSON in Javascript

```
[
    [{"key": "firstname", "Value": "David"}, {"key": "lastname", "Value": "Smith"} ],
    [{"key": "firstname", "Value": "Allen"}, {"key": "lastname", "Value": "Grover"} ],
    [{"key": "firstname", "Value": "Randy"}, {"key": "lastname", "Value": "Paul"} ]
]
```

I want to transform this in Javascript / Jquery by removing "key" and "value" and make it

```
[
    {"firstname" : "David", "lastname" : "Smith"},
    {"firstname" : "Allen", "lastname" : "Grover"},
    {"firstname" : "Randy", "lastname" : "Paul"}
]
```

And in addition am also looking to see if I can convert this json into  javascript array of objects where I can access the properties like below would be great.

```
var people =[];

people[0].firstname = "David";
people[1].lastname = "Smith";
```

Comment: You could easily do a for() loop

Comment: I've updated your question to remove the off-topic portions of your question. Asking for recommendations for a library/tool are strictly off-topic, and I'd recommend you ask that part on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to achieve this functionality:

```js
var arr = [
    [{"key": "firstname", "Value": "David"}, {"key": "lastname", "Value": "Smith"} ],
    [{"key": "firstname", "Value": "Allen"}, {"key": "lastname", "Value": "Grover"} ],
    [{"key": "firstname", "Value": "Randy"}, {"key": "lastname", "Value": "Paul"} ]
];

var final = arr.map(keys => {
  // Build the object, by attaching each key to the value
  return keys.reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key.key] = key.Value;
    return obj;
  }, {});
});
console.log(final);
```

Now, onto your question about handlebars/react/html framework. Here is an example of how you can do this dirt simple in react:

```js
var arr = [
    [{"key": "firstname", "Value": "David"}, {"key": "lastname", "Value": "Smith"} ],
    [{"key": "firstname", "Value": "Allen"}, {"key": "lastname", "Value": "Grover"} ],
    [{"key": "firstname", "Value": "Randy"}, {"key": "lastname", "Value": "Paul"} ]
];

var final = arr.map(keys => {
  // Build the object, by attaching each key to the value
  return keys.reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key.key] = key.Value;
    return obj;
  }, {});
});

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      data: props.data
    };
  }
  
  render() {
    return React.createElement('div', null,
      this.state.data.map(name =>
        React.createElement('div', null,
          `Name: ${name.firstname} ${name.lastname}`
        )
      )
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, {data: final}), document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Note:** This code is rather ugly, as I have to resort to using `React.createElement`, something of which is not required when using [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html).

Comment: Thanks @FrankerZ that was a very quick answer and is helpful. Appreciate it and full marks to your answer. Any thoughts on Templating in Handlebars or other template engines. The final goal is to show in html  as <div>FirstName : David</div><div>LastName: Smith</div> <div>FirstName : Allen</div><div>LastName: Grover</div> <div>FirstName : Randy</div><div>LastName: Paul</div>

Comment: Handlebars is fine, and you could even build this in react if you're ambitious and want to learn a cutting edge tech.

Comment: @NaveenV I spent some time, and created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YjjVwq) for you, of how you can do this in snazzy es6/jsx syntax. Check it out, react and be pretty powerful!

Comment: really appreciate your taking time and helping me on this. React is good unfortunately, I still need to learn. A handlebars version would directly go into my production code...

Answer (score 1):

Just `map` your initial data array:

```js
const data = [
  [{"key": "firstname", "Value": "David"}, {"key": "lastname", "Value": "Smith"} ],
  [{"key": "firstname", "Value": "Allen"}, {"key": "lastname", "Value": "Grover"} ],
  [{"key": "firstname", "Value": "Randy"}, {"key": "lastname", "Value": "Paul"} ]
];

const result = data.map(item => ({
  [item[0]['key']]: item[0]['Value'],
  [item[1]['key']]: item[1]['Value']
}));

console.log(result);
```

If the number of person objects per each data item could be > 2 then you need to update procedure, @FrankerZ answer is fine in that case. But if not, I would use explicit approach (without additional reducing) as more performant.

Comment: This is not the intended result, and you should try to use code snippets where possible.

Comment: @FrankerZ Thanks! I copied snippet infrastructure from your answer and looks like it works

Comment: `{firstname: David, lastname: Smith}` is the intended result, not `{David: Smith}`

Comment: @FrankerZ Thanks again

Comment: Additionally, what if there are more keys/values than just those? This limits it to a maximum of 2 keys and 2 vals.

Comment: @FrankerZ yup all you stated are correct statements.

Comment: @FrankerZ 2-limit version is more performant, but of course I agree with you and I mentioned your solution as more general.

Answer (score 1):

It makes a pretty nice functional one-liner:

```js
let arr = [[{"key": "firstname", "Value": "David"}, {"key": "lastname", "Value": "Smith"} ],[{"key": "firstname", "Value": "Allen"}, {"key": "lastname", "Value": "Grover"} ],[{"key": "firstname", "Value": "Randy"}, {"key": "lastname", "Value": "Paul"} ]]

let o = arr.map(item => item
        .reduce((a, {key, Value}) => ({[key]: Value, ...a} ), {}))

console.log(o)
```

Comment: We here edit others also if we think it is good for viewers. You are not going to read your answer in the internet by yourself only.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I saw your edit. We all know what `arr` looks like. There's no need to take up the real estate to see it again. It's common on SO to compress it into one line to save space.  For example in your answer, do we really need 32 lines to see the original object **again**? As for the rest, formatting is a matter of opinion which is off topic on SO. But I appreciate the downvote based on formatting. Thanks.

Comment: I am okay with @Mark Meyer answer and formatting. It is crisp. can you explain what this , ...a} mean?

Comment: @NaveenV, that's the spread `...` operator. It takes the accumulated object and merges it into the new object. It is similar to doing `Object.assign(a, {[key]: value})` So each time through the `reduce` loop it merges the new key/value pair with everything we've seen to far.

Comment: @MarkMeyer - I have a follow up question from this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51923644/map-reduce-json-from-api-and-display-using-handlebarsjs-in-html . Can you help fix map reduce issue there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do it as:

```
const ary = [
  [
    {
      key: "firstname",
      Value: "David"
    },
    {
      key: "lastname",
      Value: "Smith"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      key: "firstname",
      Value: "Allen"
    },
    {
      key: "lastname",
      Value: "Grover"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      key: "firstname",
      Value: "Randy"
    },
    {
      key: "lastname",
      Value: "Paul"
    }
  ]
];

let finalResult = ary.map(entry => {
  const result = {};
  entry.forEach(obj => {
    result[obj.key] = obj.Value;
  });
  return result;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(finalResult, null, 2));
// [
//   {
//     "firstname": "David",
//     "lastname": "Smith"
//   },
//   {
//     "firstname": "Allen",
//     "lastname": "Grover"
//   },
//   {
//     "firstname": "Randy",
//     "lastname": "Paul"
//   }
// ]
```

Comment: Why don't you provide a working code snippet, so we can simply execute your code to see if it works (Instead of relying on your comments)?

Comment: I never said it wasn't working; I asked why you didn't provide a code-snippet. SO built the code editor for code just like this.

Comment: @FrankerZ Here is a code I was able to get all pieces put together. Please check the question with the code here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51923644/map-reduce-json-from-api-and-display-using-handlebarsjs-in-html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `map`

```js
var arrList = [
    [{"key": "firstname", "Value": "David"}, {"key": "lastname", "Value": "Smith"} ],
    [{"key": "firstname", "Value": "Allen"}, {"key": "lastname", "Value": "Grover"} ],
    [{"key": "firstname", "Value": "Randy"}, {"key": "lastname", "Value": "Paul"} ]
];

var readyResult = arrList.map(start => {
  resultSet = {};
  start.forEach(obj => {
    resultSet[obj.key] = obj.Value;
  });
  return resultSet;
});

console.log(readyResult);
```

Comment: I think my solution is exactly same as yours. :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [
    [{
        "key": "firstname",
        "Value": "David"
    }, {
        "key": "lastname",
        "Value": "Smith"
    }],

    [{
        "key": "firstname",
        "Value": "Allen"
    }, {
        "key": "lastname",
        "Value": "Grover"
    }],

    [{
        "key": "firstname",
        "Value": "Randy"
    }, {
        "key": "lastname",
        "Value": "Paul"
    }]
];

var result = data.map(v1 => {
    var vtemp = v1.map(v2 => ({
        [Object.values(v2)[0]]: Object.values(v2)[1]
    }))
    return { ...vtemp[0],
        ...vtemp[1]
    }
})

console.log(result);

console.log(result[0].firstname);
```